# How much commenting should you put in a program?

Tags: comments

I'm finishing my first "real world" program and I'm not sure how much commenting is too much commenting. What exactly is best practice when adding comments? Do I explain every step or not bother with the "how" and focus more on the "why" or is there no such thing as too much commenting?

Comment: Real programmers don't comment their code - it was hard to write, it should be hard to understand. ;)

Comment: There is no single, "correct" answer to this question. You will get a lot of opinions on this topic, but in practice it will depend largely on the norms of whatever team/group/company in which you're coding.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically if you are working in a team there should be an established amount of commenting/documentation that is expected of you.  If you are keeping the code for yourself you can use as little commenting as you want.  ALTHOUGH you should try to keep your code clean, readable, and easy enough to understand with a little thought.  If you are keeping your code modular by using functions/methods you should probably describe what that function is doing. ex:

```
# Calls LS on the ROOT directory then prints output
def main():
    bashCommand = "ls /"
    process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = process.communicate()[0]
    print output
```

A bad practice would be leaving decent chunks of code commented out (in your end product).  Here is an example of bad practice:

```
def searchPcGame(game):
    #need to parse id="search_items"
    url = 'http://www.pcgamer.com/search/%s' %game
    rv = requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(rv.text)
    zz = soup.find_all(id="search_items")
    titles = [a.get_text() for a in soup.find_all('h3')]
    # zzSoup = BeautifulSoup(zz.text)
    # foo = []
    # foo.append(articlesSoup)
    # return titles
    return zz
```